# Разница ParseInt, ParseFloat и Number

Tags: javascript, javascript-faq

Всем привет! Скажите, в чём разница между функциями `ParseFloat`, `ParseInt` и `Number`? В результате этих функций строка преобразуется в число.

```js
alert('3' + 2);
//--------------------------//
alert(parseFloat('3') + 2);
alert(parseInt('3') + 2);
alert(Number('3') + 2);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## В двух словах:

`parseFloat` и `parseInt` преобразуют в число максимальную соответствующую подстроку, с начала строки, отбросив предварительно пробельные символы.

`Number` - целую строку, так же отбросив предварительно пробельные символы.

Различие можно увидеть на примере

```js
//--------------------------//
console.log(parseFloat('3a'));
console.log(parseInt('3a'));
console.log(Number('3a'));
```

---

### Развернутый ответ

Для более полного понимания различий можно обратиться к [спецификации](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/)

#### Начать можно с [конструктора Number](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-number-constructor-number-value)

Если данная функция вызывается без `new`, то

1. Если не передали параметров результат будет `+0`
2. Если параметр (value) передан, то будет возвращен результат вызова *ToNumber(value)*

Где [*ToNumber(value)*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-tonumber) - это абстрактная функция, вызываемая, когда необходимо получить числовое значение.

**Стоит обратить внимание**, что, в отличие от рассмотренных ниже функций, параметр `value` будет приведен к строке только в некоторых случаях.

В случае, если `value` был приведен к строке, эта строка должна удовлетворять [грамматике для StringNumericLiteral](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-tonumber-applied-to-the-string-type). Отличие данной грамматики от обычного [NumericLiteral](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#prod-NumericLiteral), который определяет правила для литералов чисел, в том, что:

- *StringNumericLiteral* может включать в себя лидирующие и/или оконечные пробелы и/или разделители строк.
- *StringNumericLiteral* в десятичном виде может иметь любое количество лидирующих нулей.
- *StringNumericLiteral* в десятичном виде может включать `+` или `-` для указания знака числа.
- *StringNumericLiteral* с пустой строкой, либо содержащий только пробельный символы будет конвертирован в `+0`.
- *Infinity* и *-Infinity* будут распознаны как *StringNumericLiteral*, но не как *NumericLiteral*.

---

#### [Функция parseInt](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-parseint-string-radix)

Отличительной особенностью данной функции является возможность передать вторым параметром основание системы счисления, в которой находится число в строке. По умолчанию данный параметр имеет значение: 10.

Стоит отметить, что первый аргумент **всегда** приводится к строке.

Алгоритм работы данной функции весьма прост:

1. Отбрасываются пробельные символы с начала строки
2. Определяется знак числа
3. Выставляет флаг *нужно ли отбрасывать префикс*, в том случае, если основание равно 16 или не передано.
4. Если нужно отбрасывать префикс:

   1. отбрасываются первые два символа, если они равны *0x* или *0X*
   2. основанию устанавливается значение 16
5. Если в строке присутствуют символы не соответствующие основанию, то выбирается подстрока, перед первым таким символом.
6. Вычисляется математическое целочисленное значение, соответствующее выбранной подстроке. Символы A-Z и a-z используются для представления значений от 10 до 35 в соответствующих системах счисления.
7. полученный результат умножается на знак и возвращается.

Как можно заметить, в отличие от описанной выше функции *Number*, для разбора используется не вся строка, распознается *только* префикс для шестнадцатеричных чисел, но при этом добавляется возможность указать основание системы счисления от 2 до 36

---

#### [Функция parseFloat](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-parseint-string-radix)

Как и в *parseInt*, в данной функции **всегда** идет приведение аргумента к строке.

Алгоритм схож с работой функции *parseInt*

1. Отбрасываются пробельные символы с начала строки
2. Определяется удовлетворяет ли оставшаяся строка или любой из ее префиксов [синтаксису StrDecimalLiteral](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#prod-StrDecimalLiteral)

   1. если нет, возвращается *NaN*
   2. если да - берется максимальный префикс.
3. Возвращается соответствующее число.

Как можно заметить, по сравнению с *Number*, для разбора используется часть строки, не допустимы никакие префиксы вроде *0x*, *0b*, *0o*. В отличие от *parseInt* допустима *e*-нотация

---

#### Больше примеров

```js
function showOutput(str, base) {
  console.log('строка:"' + str + '"', 'Number:', Number(str), 'parseInt:', parseInt(str, base), 'base:', base || 10, 'parseFloat:', parseFloat(str));
}

showOutput('  ');
showOutput('10');
showOutput('3a');
showOutput('0x10');
showOutput('0x10s');
showOutput('0o10');
showOutput('1e2');
showOutput('1e2', 16);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: О, благодарю :) Через 8 минут приму

Comment: @АлександрАнтонов, оказывается уже был похожий вопрос, там в ответе еще пример с `parseInt`

Comment: Ну я с parseInt знаю разницу, а тут...

Comment: О, ещё можно вспомнить про `Number('0xFF')`

Comment: @AlexeyTen, ага, в комментариях к дубликату проскакивала такая запись :-)

Comment: А ещё же есть экспоненциальная запись `1e5`

Comment: @AlexeyTen, попробую развернуть ответ :-) чтобы все неоднозначности убрать