# Как преобразовать строку в число (numeric из string)?

Tags: javascript

Как  вот из этой строки -  `"2"` сделать `numeric`?

Comment: @Visman ой ли? разница между четко названными функциями и вообще в целом способы перевода из строки в число - разные вещи

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, выберите сами оригинальный вопрос. Их там на несколько страниц, если не ошибаюсь.

Comment: @unicorn23 почему он дубликат, если он не дубликат?

Comment: @Visman не увидел нескольких страниц. либо вы не на то ссылку дали

Answer (score 11):

Есть еще вариант использовать двойное побитовое НЕ

```js
var num = '2';
console.log(typeof ~~num);
```

Comment: с битовыми операциями надо быть аккуратным, так как они работают **только** с int32: `~~'4294967296' === 0`

Answer (score 11):

- самый быстрый способ умножение на 1 (`str * 1`)

```js
var str = '2.2';
console.log((str * 1) + 2);
```

- по аналогии выше: деление на 1 или вычитание 0

```js
var str = '2.2';
console.log((str / 1) + 2);
console.log((str - 0) + 2);
```

- чууууть медленнее добавление плюса перед строкой (`+str`)

```js
var str = '2.2';
console.log((+str) + 2);
```

- для целого и дробного с помощью `Number`

```js
var str = '2.2';
console.log(Number(str) + 2);
```

- вариант через `round` только для целого числа

```js
var str = '2';    
console.log(Math.round(str) + 2);
```

- `parseInt` (для целых) и `parseFloat` (для дробных)

Для `parseInt`  иногда стоит указать систему счисления.

```js
var strFloat = '2.2';    
var strInt = '2';    
console.log(parseFloat(strFloat) + 2);
console.log(parseInt(strInt, 10) + 2);
```

Если не указать систему счисления, то может быть так:

```
var result = parseInt("010", 10) == 10; // Returns true
var result = parseInt("010") == 10; // Returns false
```

---

Но везде надо быть осторожным. Если в строке встречаются не только числа, но и другие символы, то это может не сработать. Например как написано тут: [Разница ParseInt, ParseFloat и Number](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/633467/191482)

Comment: Если верить MDN, у parseFloat всего один аргумент и система счисления всегда 10

Comment: @andreymal так точно. поправил

Comment: откуда дровишки про _самый быстрый_? :)

Answer (score 10):

Если я правильно понял, и вам нужно из строки получить число, то используйте для этого [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

```js
var str = '2';
console.log(str + 2);
str = parseInt(str);
console.log(str + 2);
```

Comment: Я всех лайкнул, а тебя лайкать не буду, потому что ты мне не нравишься :D Большинство моих вопросов забрал :)

Comment: @Yuri ТВОИХ вопросов?

Comment: Ну только хочу ответить на вопрос, а тут уже ты написал. И при том пишешь те же идеи, что и я хотел предложить :)

Answer (score 6):

Есть еще вариант, писать знак `+` перед `string` c цифрами.

```js
var str = '2';
console.log(str + 2);
console.log(+str + 2);
```

Answer (score 5):

Еще можно сделать с помощью динамической типизации языка JavaScript

```js
    var x = "2"
    console.log(typeof x)
    x=x*1
    console.log(typeof x)
```

после этой операции x будет числом

Comment: Да, да ЛЮБАЯ попытка сделать какуую нибудь сугуубо