# Сложение чисел. Ошибка

Tags: javascript

Не удаётся сложить переменную с числом и число.

```
var num = 5;
alert(num+5);
```

В итоге получается 55, а должно 10. А если сложить так...

```
alert(5+5);
```

то всё в порядке - получается 10.

В чем проблема? Что я не так делаю?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В вашем примере как раз таки все правильно считает

Comment: А как тогда у меня тоже самое показывает не 10, а 55? От библиотеки JQuery это ведь зависить не может....

Comment: Данный пример, если вы в нем ничего не меняете, никак не может вывести 55. И jquery тут не при чем

Comment: Значит не то же самое, давайте весь ваш код с «тем же самым»

Comment: Скорее всего Вы складываете строку с числом. Строка получается из-за того что Вы берете значение из DOM ноды строковое по умолчанию. Приведите код с ошибкой.

Comment: ты значит значение `num` где-то считываешь и оно у тебя как строка

Comment: Вы думаете картинкой переубедить нас в том, что приведенный вами код выводит 55?

Comment: Я понял свою ошибку. Значение получается из DOM. Ответ ниже помог.

Comment: @ДенисНебесный еще один вариант конвертации строки в int https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/699604/191482

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В оригинальном коде у вас переменная является строкой и оператор, как и предполагается объединяет строку со значением 5.
Вам нужно вызвать `num = parseInt(num)`, чтобы привести к number и сложить два значения.

Comment: `num = '0XF'; parseInt(num) === 15` :)