# Помогите решить простой вопрос JS. Строку в число, умножить и вывести обратно

Tags: javascript, jquery

Задача я думаю простая, но я нуб. Ищу решение еще со вчера уже мозги кипят(

Пока есть одна строка

```
<p class="price">1000</p>
```

Нужно найти эту строку по Классу (потому что таких строк будет потом много) и умножить строку на число (допустим 25), чтобы обратно в ту же строку записалось умноженное число. Как это реализовать я не понимаю.

Чтобы на выходе получилось так:

```
<p class="price">25000</p>
```

Сделать надо на JavaScript

Answer (score 3):

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.price'), function(element) {
  element.textContent = element.textContent * 25;
});
```

```html
<p class="price">1000</p>
<p class="price">2000</p>
<p class="price">100</p>
```

---

**Дополнительная информация:**

- [Document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [Loop Over querySelectorAll Matches](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/loop-queryselectorall-matches/)
- [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)
- [Function.prototype.call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)
- [Node.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

Answer (score 2):

Ты же сам описал всё. Нужно только применить логику.

Например, изучив методы `jquery` можно вспомнить, что к элементу можно применить метод **[text](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function)** с колбэк функцией, которая может вернуть любые данные.

Выглядит он так:

```
Function( Integer index, String text ) => String
```

Соответственно:

- Используешь селектор `.`, чтобы взять данные по классу.
- Применяешь метод `text` с колбэк функцией, у которой вторым параметром передается значение того самого элемента
- В колбэке возвращаешь значение этого самого элемента умноженного на 1000

  **Заметка:** т.к. значение элемента (`text`) строковое, то его нужно будет предварительно преобразовать в число одним из способов, описанных тут: **[Как сделать numeric из string?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/699730/191482)**

Answer (score 1):

Без jQuery, вариант для целых значений:

```js
const COEFF = 25;
let items = document.getElementsByClassName('price');
for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  let item = items[i];
  item.innerText = parseInt(item.innerText, 10) * COEFF;
}
```

```html
<p class="price">200</p>
<p class="price">1000</p>
<p class="fixedprice">1000</p>
<p class="price">3000</p>
```