# JavaScript, не умножается с дробью?

Tags: javascript

Привет, есть простой калькулятор на javascript. Он берет значения из введенных input'ов и умножает. Количество и цена за один товар. Взял эти значения в переменные они были типа string, через parseInt перевел их в number и теперь они работают, но дробь никак не показывает. К примеру 4*2 = 8. 4*2.9 = 8, 4*3=12. Знаю что parseInt превращает в целое число но как по другому из строк получить нужный мне тип переменные

Comment: есть еще `parseFloat`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать numeric из string?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/699598/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-numeric-%d0%b8%d0%b7-string)

Comment: Лучше выложи сюда код, так будет понятней, что да как...  Вопрос по сути понятны, по этому ответил, но сложно говорить, что-то, когда не видишь код... Добавь пример в вопрос...  Надо нажать "править" под вопросом...

Comment: @Air смысл кода, если это дубликат. В дубликате все варианты рабочие

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, а если человеку трудно в чужом коде что-то понять? Лично мне понятнее, когда показывают ошибку именно в моем коде...  Тем более, чем плохо, если на сайте будут разнообразные примеры?

Comment: @Air дубликаты создали не просто так. И в дубликате нет миллионнострочного кода. Там простые, понятные примеры, которые поймет даже енот

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ну если человек спрашивает, я же могу игнорировать его вопрос... Уверен, он видел твои комменты о дубликате и что еще есть parseFloat... Ну  а раз спрашивает, значит не разобрался, а я не могу разобраться, если не могу видеть, что да как он сделал..

Comment: Скорее всего Вам надо не parseInt, а parseFloat

Answer (score 0):

parseInt, не просто переводи строку в число, а еще и отсекает дробную часть...  или надо использовать в место parseInt  Number или просто

```
inpute.value * 1
```

Умножение строки на единицу преобразовывает строку в число

Comment: Сделал, и работает теперь с дробью в виде 1.34 * 134. Но никак не работает если одна из чисел 0.0002 к примеру , даже 0.2 не работает