# Переменные склеиваются

Tags: javascript, массивы, int, строки

Возникла проблема, у меня есть 2 переменные (int),но вместо того чтобы сложится, они склеиваются, хотя по сути не должны.

```js
var addTwoNumbers = function(l1, l2) { //Принимает 2 массива
  let result = 0
  let one = l1.reverse().join('') //Переворачиваем массив и преобразуем в строку
  let two = l2.reverse().join('') //Переворачиваем массиви и преобразуем в строку
  return one + two //складываем 
};


console.log(addTwoNumbers([2, 4, 3], [5, 6, 4]))
```

Я получаю ответ 342465

Comment: "хотя по сути не должны" - почему, если вы складываете строки?

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/operators#slozhenie-strok-pri-pomoschi-binarnogo

Answer (score 2):

Ответ находится прямо в вопросе....

В комментариях в коде указано:

> Переворачиваем массив и преобразуем в **СТРОКУ**

А что делает между собой знак плюс со строками?

---

Как строку преобразовать в число можно подглядеть тут:

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/699730/191482

Comment: извиняюсь, имел ввиду из массива [2,4,3] в 342, а это число

Comment: Нет..... **[join делает строку](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join#summary)**

Answer (score 0):

```
var addTwoNumbers = function(l1, l2) { //Принимает 2 массива
  let result = 0
  let one = l1.reverse().join('') //Переворачиваем массив и преобразуем в строку
  let two = l2.reverse().join('') //Переворачиваем массиви и преобразуем в строку
  return +one + +two //складываем 
};

console.log(addTwoNumbers([2, 4, 3], [5, 6, 4]))
```

Когда вы работаете с двумя строками, интерпретатор не будет заниматься приведением типов - это две строки и этого достаточно. "123" + "123" - конкатенация.
Если вы работаете с двумя разными типами данных - тогда да, в дело вступает приведение типов. 123 + "123" - приведение типов.