# Сохранение данных пользователя Js localStorage

Tags: javascript

Подсказали использовать localStorage [ТУТ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1448437/%d0%a1%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f-js/1448460?noredirect=1#comment2586571_1448460) но появился такой вопрос, как правильно присвоить

```
var clicks = 0; // Счетчик кликов
var clickPower = 0.001; // Начально значение клика

const onClick = () => {
    document.getElementById('clicks-count').innerText = (clicks + clickPower).toFixed(3);
    clicks = clicks + clickPower;
}

document.getElementById('big-btn').addEventListener('click', onClick)
```

Пытался сделать что-то в таком роде

```
var clicks = localStorage.getItem('clicks') || 0;
```

Но выдает ошибку Uncaught TypeError: (clicks + clickPower).toFixed is not a function

Comment: в текущем коде не может быть такой проблемы....

Comment: `var clicks = localStorage.getItem('clicks')` --- извлекатеся строка.....надо преобразовать в число скорее всего

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В коде:

```
var clicks = localStorage.getItem('clicks')
```

из хранилища приходит строка. Строка и символ `+` дают конкатенацию строки. Метода `toFixed` нет у строки. Но есть у чисел. Как следствие, надо строку, которую достали из хранилища, перевести (кастануть) в число

Comment: Я как понимаю что сюда 

document.getElementById('clicks-count').innerText = (clicks + clickPower).toFixed(3);

выводится строка а должно выводить число, если не сложно подскажите пожалуйста как правильно прописать вывод числа ну и чтобы работал .toFixed(3)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/699598/191482  - как сделать из строки число.... делать это надо после получения данных изхранилища. чтобы не засорять код дальше