# не выводится через switch записанная переменная

Tags: javascript

```
let pin = prompt("Введите число от 1 до 9");

switch (pin) {
    case pin = 1:
        console.log("Один");
        break;
    case pin = 2:
        console.log("Два");
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Из `prompt` всегда возвращается строка. Чтобы сравнивать с числом, нужно привести данные к числу

Как привести строку к числу можно посмотреть тут:

**[Как преобразовать строку в число (numeric из string)?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/699598/191482)**

Также сам switch записан не правильно. Как писать правильно - посмотрите внимательно в **[документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)**

Answer (score 4):

> не выводится через switch записанная переменная

Дело в том что `prompt` возвращает строку. И сам `switch` записан не правильно

```js
let pin = prompt("Введите число от 1 до 9");

switch (pin) {
    case '1':
        console.log("Один");
        break;
    case '2':
        console.log("Два");
        break;
}
```