# parseInt(null, 24) === 23. Почему?

Tags: javascript

Каким образом преобразованные в число NaN и 24 трансформировались в 23?

```js
for(var i = 1; i <= 36; i++)
  console.log(i, parseInt(null, i), parseInt("null", i));
```

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Разница ParseInt, ParseFloat и Number](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/633464/186999)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Простое совпадение.

```
parseInt(null, 24)
```

означает привести строку `"null"` (строку потому, что первый параметр, переданный `parseInt()` всегда конвертируется в строку) в число в системе счисления с основанием 24.

"n" в данном случае - 23 (потому что есть 9 цифр (кроме нуля) и "n" - 14 буква алфавита. 9 + 14 = 23).

"u" - 30. Уже выходит за пределы системы счисления с основанием 24. Поэтому возвращается `23`, то есть число, полученное до этого момента.

Иными словами `parseInt(null, 24)` === `parseInt("null", 24)` === `parseInt("n", 24)` === `23`.

Отсюда и ответ - `23 === 23` - `true`.

`parseInt(null, m) === 23` всегда даст `true`, если `m` находится в пределе от 24 до 30.

Конкретно этот случай интересен лишь тем, что в первый параметр передается `null` как значение, а не как строка. Это вас и смутило. И `null` - это, пожалуй, единственное значение в языке, при конвертации в число с основанием 24 которого результат максимально приближен к самому основанию системы счисления.

> Каким образом преобразованные в число NaN и 24 трансформировались в
>   23?

И насчет вот этой части. Это не `NaN` **и** `24` "трансформировались", а только `null`, которое при конвертации в число (с основанием 24+) средствами метода `parseInt` дает 23.

То есть метод `parseInt` принимает в качестве первого аргумента то, *что* нужно сконвертировать, а в качестве второго то, что будет является *основанием системы счисления*.

Больше о самом методе [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), о "системах счисления" [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) (больше по соответствующему запросу в гугле; посмотрите также именно про "*основание* системы счисления"), другие ответы на этот вопрос (на английском, правда) [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6459758/parseintnull-24-23-wait-what).

Comment: отличное объяснение!

Comment: "u".charCodeAt(0)
117,  "l".charCodeAt(0) 108, "l".charCodeAt(0) 108. 9 цифр получили + "n" - 14ая буква алфавита. Какая связь между ними и почему прибавляются?

Comment: @HovhannesShaxulyan не путайте коды символов и номера букв в алфавите. Коды символов - это номера unicode-позиций этих символов. А в приведенном мной примере я говорю совершенно о других вещах. В стандартной (привычной нам) системе счисления 10 цифр. В 24-основательной системе 24 цифры. Однако человечество решило не придумывать им специальные письменные обозначения, а вместо этого использовать существующие буквы английского алфавита. Так a становится 10, b - 11, c - 12, и так далее (до 23, то есть "n").

Comment: @HovhannesShaxulyan а вообще советую вам поиграться с методом `parseInt` с разными радиксами (основаниями) и посмотреть результаты. Так сразу понятнее станет.