# Почему то не делает сортировку... Помогите пожалуйста

Tags: javascript

Пишет ошибку: Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'sorted' has already been declared
Должен отработать по возрастанию

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll( ".results-container" )

    const sorted = [...elements].sort((a, b) => {
        const priceElA = a.querySelector(".amount")
        const priceElB = b.querySelector(".amount")
        const getPrice = (el) => parseInt(el.innerHTML)
        return getPrice(priceElA) - getPrice(priceElB)
      })
      const resultEl = document.querySelector(".results-container2")
      resultEl.innerHTML = null
      sorted.forEach(el => resultEl.appendChild(el))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="results-container2"><div class="container results-container">
        
    <div class="page collapse show">

        <div class="row align-items-center">
             <div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-4 text-muted">
                <div class="float-left small">
                    <span class="kod" title="">
                        <i class="text-muted">
                        </i>
                    </span>
                     <span>
                          
                        <a style="white-space: nowrap;" href="https://www.google.ru/search?q=AVA COOLING SYSTEMS&nbsp;VW7536+&amp;newwindow=1&amp;biw=1366&amp;bih=667&amp;tbm=isch&amp;tbo=u&amp;source=univ&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=0CC8QsARqFQoTCMDCoO70jMkCFQGFLAodrT0GFw" target="_blank"> Google Фото</a>
                         <br>
                         <a href="https://yandex.ru/images/search?text=AVA COOLING SYSTEMS&nbsp;VW7536+&amp;from=tabbar" target="_blank"> Yandex Фото</a>
                         
                     </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-7 col-lg-7 col-sm-9 col-md-10 col-8">
                <div class="cardprod">
                    
                    <div class="product-name"> Вентилятор радиатора
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                <div id="productload" class="modal fade show" style="z-index: 99999999999;">
                </div>
                <div class="float-left small">
                    <span title="артикул товара: VW7536" class="mr-3">
                        <i class="text-muted">арт:
                        </i>VW7536
                    </span>
                    <span title="в упаковке: 1  шт" class="mr-3"><i class="text-muted">упак: </i>1 шт
                    </span>
                    <span title="миним. норма отпуска 1 шт">
                        <i class="text-muted ml-2">мин
                        </i>:&nbsp;1 шт
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="manufactur float-right small text-muted mr-2">AVA COOLING SYSTEMS
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-3 col-sm-9 col-md-10 col-12 text-right addcartpost2">
                <form class="addcartpost" action="." method="POST">
                
                    <span class="text-muted small rt mr-1">
                        
                        
                        <small title="время доставки, дн." class="px-1 mr-1" style="border:solid 1px #17a2b8; border-top:solid 3px #17a2b8; font-size: 9px">3</small>
                        1 шт
                        
                        
                    </span>
                
                        
                    
                    <div class="amount">
                            2&nbsp;787,73
                    </div>

                
                

<i class="i bi-file-minus" title="уменьшение">
</i>
<input class="id_pr" type="hidden" name="id_pr" value="999999371145" required="" id="id_pr">
<input class="product id_quantity" name="quantity" type="number" value="1" min="1" step="1" required="" id="id_quantity" max="1">
<input class="artikul" type="hidden" name="artikul" value="VW7536" id="artikul">
<input class="brend" type="hidden" name="brend" value="AVA COOLING SYSTEMS" id="brend">
<input class="name" type="hidden" name="name" value="Вентилятор радиатора" id="name">
<input class="upakovka_f" type="hidden" name="upakovka_f" value="1" id="upakovka_f">
<input class="shtuk_e" type="hidden" name="shtuk_e" value="шт" id="shtuk_e">
<input class="min_kol" type="hidden" name="min_kol" value="1" id="min_kol">
<input type="hidden" name="update" value="False" id="id_update">
<i class="bi bi-file-plus" title="увеличение">
</i>
<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="">
<div class="addbasket float-rigth">
    <input id="add-toast" class="update" type="submit" value="купить">
</div>

                </form>
            </div>


            

        </div>
        <hr>

    </div>

</div><div class="container results-container">
        
    <div class="page collapse show">

        <div class="row align-items-center">
             <div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-4 text-muted">
                <div class="float-left small">
                    <span class="kod" title="">
                        <i class="text-muted">
                        </i>
                    </span>
                     <span>
                          
                        <a style="white-space: nowrap;" href="https://www.google.ru/search?q=AVA COOLING SYSTEMS&nbsp;VW7534+&amp;newwindow=1&amp;biw=1366&amp;bih=667&amp;tbm=isch&amp;tbo=u&amp;source=univ&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=0CC8QsARqFQoTCMDCoO70jMkCFQGFLAodrT0GFw" target="_blank"> Google Фото</a>
                         <br>
                         <a href="https://yandex.ru/images/search?text=AVA COOLING SYSTEMS&nbsp;VW7534+&amp;from=tabbar" target="_blank"> Yandex Фото</a>
                         
                     </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-7 col-lg-7 col-sm-9 col-md-10 col-8">
                <div class="cardprod">
                    
                    <div class="product-name"> Вентилятор радиатора ЛЕВЫЙ AUDI A3 [8PA]/ VW GOLF V PLUS/ PASSAT CC
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                <div id="productload" class="modal fade show" style="z-index: 99999999999;">
                </div>
                <div class="float-left small">
                    <span title="артикул товара: VW7534" class="mr-3">
                        <i class="text-muted">арт:
                        </i>VW7534
                    </span>
                    <span title="в упаковке: 1  шт" class="mr-3"><i class="text-muted">упак: </i>1 шт
                    </span>
                    <span title="миним. норма отпуска 1 шт">
                        <i class="text-muted ml-2">мин
                        </i>:&nbsp;1 шт
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="manufactur float-right small text-muted mr-2">AVA COOLING SYSTEMS
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-3 col-sm-9 col-md-10 col-12 text-right addcartpost2">
                <form class="addcartpost" action="." method="POST">
                
                    <span class="text-muted small rt mr-1">
                        
                        
                        <small title="время доставки, дн." class="px-1 mr-1" style="border:solid 1px #17a2b8; border-top:solid 3px #17a2b8; font-size: 9px">10</small>
                        2 шт
                        
                        
                    </span>
                
                        
                    
                    <div class="amount">
                            6&nbsp;411,78
                    </div>

                
                

<i class="i bi-file-minus" title="уменьшение">
</i>
<input class="id_pr" type="hidden" name="id_pr" value="999999487731" required="" id="id_pr">
<input class="product id_quantity" name="quantity" type="number" value="1" min="1" step="1" required="" id="id_quantity" max="2">
<input class="artikul" type="hidden" name="artikul" value="VW7534" id="artikul">
<input class="brend" type="hidden" name="brend" value="AVA COOLING SYSTEMS" id="brend">
<input class="name" type="hidden" name="name" value="Вентилятор радиатора ЛЕВЫЙ AUDI A3 [8PA]/ VW GOLF V PLUS/ PASSAT CC" id="name">
<input class="upakovka_f" type="hidden" name="upakovka_f" value="1" id="upakovka_f">
<input class="shtuk_e" type="hidden" name="shtuk_e" value="шт" id="shtuk_e">
<input class="min_kol" type="hidden" name="min_kol" value="1" id="min_kol">
<input type="hidden" name="update" value="False" id="id_update">
<i class="bi bi-file-plus" title="увеличение">
</i>
<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="">
<div class="addbasket float-rigth">
    <input id="add-toast" class="update" type="submit" value="купить">
</div>

                </form>
            </div>


            

        </div>
        <hr>

    </div>

</div><div class="container results-container">
        
        <div class="page-header titlecat h4">
            
            <small class="text-title">ЗАПЧАСТИ ДЛЯ ТО&nbsp;
                <i class="bi bi-chevron-right">
                </i>&nbsp;
            </small>
            
            
            <a href="/catalog/406/">Фильтры масляные
            </a>
            
        </div>
        
    <div class="page collapse show">

        <div class="row align-items-center">
             <div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-4 text-muted">
                <div class="float-left small">
                    <span class="kod" title="код товара: ">
                        <i class="text-muted">
                        </i>код: 167958
                    </span>
                     <span>
                          
                             <img src="" width="90" height="66" onerror="this.src=''">
                          
                     </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-7 col-lg-7 col-sm-9 col-md-10 col-8">
                <div class="cardprod">
                    
                    <a class="product-name" id="load-product" title="подробнее..." href="/catalog/406/167958/" data-image="/media/product-img/168/167958.jpg">Фильтр масляный Logan, Sandero, Largus, Duster, Megane I-II, Clio I-III, Kangoo, Laguna, Almera (G11/15) 12-- (24)
                    </a>
                    
                </div>
                <div id="productload" class="modal fade show" style="z-index: 99999999999;">
                </div>
                <div class="float-left small">
                    <span title="артикул товара: NF1018" class="mr-3">
                        <i class="text-muted">арт:
                        </i>NF1018
                    </span>
                    <span title="в упаковке: 20  шт" class="mr-3"><i class="text-muted">упак: </i>20 шт
                    </span>
                    <span title="миним. норма отпуска 1 шт">
                        <i class="text-muted ml-2">мин
                        </i>:&nbsp;1 шт
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="manufactur float-right small text-muted mr-2">Невский фильтр
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-3 col-sm-9 col-md-10 col-12 text-right addcartpost2">
                <form class="addcartpost" action="." method="POST">
                
                    <span class="text-muted small rt mr-1">
                        
                        
                        11 шт
                        
                        
                    </span>
                
                        
                    
                    <div class="amount">
                            78,40
                    </div>

                
                

<i class="i bi-file-minus" title="уменьшение">
</i>
<input class="id_pr" type="hidden" name="id_pr" value="167958" required="" id="id_pr">
<input class="product id_quantity" name="quantity" type="number" value="1" min="1" step="1" required="" id="id_quantity" max="11">
<input class="artikul" type="hidden" name="artikul" value="NF1018" id="artikul">
<input class="brend" type="hidden" name="brend" value="Невский фильтр" id="brend">
<input class="name" type="hidden" name="name" value="Фильтр масляный Logan, Sandero, Largus, Duster, Megane I-II, Clio I-III, Kangoo, Laguna, Almera (G11/15) 12-- (24)" id="name">
<input class="upakovka_f" type="hidden" name="upakovka_f" value="20" id="upakovka_f">
<input class="shtuk_e" type="hidden" name="shtuk_e" value="шт" id="shtuk_e">
<input class="min_kol" type="hidden" name="min_kol" value="1" id="min_kol">
<input type="hidden" name="update" value="False" id="id_update">
<i class="bi bi-file-plus" title="увеличение">
</i>
<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="">
<div class="addbasket float-rigth">
    <input id="add-toast" class="update" type="submit" value="купить">
</div>

                </form>
            </div>


            

        </div>
        <hr>

    </div>

</div></div>
```

Comment: Просто у тебя JS наверное внутри контейнера висит  и потом вставляется в другой.. вот и всё

Comment: нет ,  не внутри контейнера

Comment: Может вы этот кусок кода два раза в один скрипт или на одну страницу инклудите?

Comment: Нет, вот сейчас выложил код и он теперь неправильно фильтрует, должен по возрастанию.

Comment: ваш  parseInt(el.innerHTML) работает совершенно не так, как вы ожидаете. запустите `parseInt("\n              6&nbsp;411,78\n            ")`

Comment: да точно! а как правильно!

Comment: _Identifier 'sorted' has already been declared_ - говорит что ты два раза определяешь переменную `sorted`

Comment: parseInt(el.innerHTML)  принимает похоже пробелы  и фильтрует как строку в итоге

Comment: Всем спасибо!!!

Comment: [parseInt - отбрасывает начальные пробельные символы, потом берет знак, если есть, и подряд идущие цифры, остальное игнорирует](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/633467/186999)